# Can anyone please suggest a single word which represents the quality of a person who can turn an obstacle into an opportunity

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, vocabulary

Can anyone please suggest a single word which represents the quality of a person who can turn an obstacle into an opportunity. The person will be strong even in the worst situations and will convert every situation into an opportunity. I would need a one word adjective or noun which describes the above skills. I can accept this word from any language. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 1):

An "opportunist".

The phrase, "When life gives you lemons, make lemonade." was coined to describe an opportunist.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_life_gives_you_lemons,_make_lemonade

Comment: An "opportunist" is someone who takes advantage of the misfortunes of others.

Comment: This is the right answer. An *opportunist* is [opportunistic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunistic): "taking advantage of opportunities as they arise." It might, but often does not, have anything to do with the misfortune of others.